# How to render a special emoji (ོ) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I render some special emojis (e.g., ོ) in Flutter? When I tried to show them on the page, I got garbled characters as shown below.

[image]

Any ideas?

I tried to use a different font in the theme.

```dart
textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(
  Theme.of(context).textTheme,
),
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: It's a matter of the font not supporting those characters (that's what's the question mark means, a missing character replaced by some placeholder). Just search and pick a font that includes the emojis you want and it'll work.